# How to add Image in Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add Image to the activity using **Android Jetpack Compose** but it is giving error:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Image(bitmap = imageFromResource(res = resources, resId =R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the screenshot of Android Studio]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either of these can be used to get the image resource.

Use the [painterResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#painterresource) API to load either vector drawables or rasterized asset formats like PNGs. You don't need to know the type of the drawable, simply use painterResource.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource

        Image(painterResource(id = imageResource), contentDescription = contentDescription)
```

OR

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.res.imageResource

        Image(ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = imageResource), contentDescription = contentDescription)
```

OR

```
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource

        Image(ImageVector.vectorResource(id = imageResource), contentDescription = contentDescription)
```

Answer (score 9):

most of the cases for local image loading can be done using **painterResource** in **Image**

for example:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), contentDescription = "")
```

or if you are interested in changing the color of the image asset, then use **Icon** with **painterResource**

```
Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Red)
```

or if you want to load from **Remote URL** then use **Coil**

add dependency:

```
implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.6.1"
```

and then use it like below:

```
 CoilImage(
                data = "https://www.instaily.com/images/android.jpg",
                contentDescription = "android",
                alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(.60f),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                loading = {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                            color = Teal200
                        )
                    )
                },
                error = {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                            color = Teal200
                        )
                    )
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another alternative working code for this problem:

**Code:**

```
     Image(
          painter = painterResource(R.drawable.happy_meal_small),
          contentDescription = null
      )
```

**Output:**

[image]